# Statistical quality criteria for classifiers and recommenders

Tags: classification, recommender-system, metric

I want to know several points regarding the evaluation of data sets.
I would like to know which metrics are the best for the evaluation of:

a) recommenders and classifiers

b) online and offline experiments (recommender)

c) user-based and item-based recommenders

It would be also great to get some reference to good sources.

Comment: Do you mean risk? Risk integrates recommendation/classification error for its probability. I can't see the meaning of metric in this context.

Comment: I mean recall, precision, accuracy, rmse, diversity, coverage, confidence, trust, novelty, diversity etc, etc. For example, I know that serendipity is good for online data for recommender, it is not necessary to evaluate the offline experiment. Which metrics is most valuable for which case?!

Comment: Your question seems very broad. Maybe you can further edit it to be more specific. Also what have tried to find a solution by yourself?

Comment: @HorstGrünbusch, probably you are right. Is it possible to discuss at first only the second part of questions. I would like to know,what is a difference by recommender, when I analyze the data set from offline and online experiments. This question is of course very< general, but I also agree, if somebody could get me a good link instead of discussion. My personally experience I did with the chapter 8 in the book "Recommender systems handbook". I want to deepen my knowledge in this area and every help or discussion is welcome.